# MySQL DATETIME to MONTH only

Tags: mysql

i made a sql statement and looks fine i first wanted to show only weekly dates like this one

> WHERE WEEK(date_add) = WEEK(UTC_TIMESTAMP())

this works fine outcome = '2017-02-27 12:08:24'

For MONTHS i change WEEK to MONTH or YEAR works great. But then someone asked me to show only the date like outcome = 'april' or 'juli' and then i was like how do i do that? so i searched on google and found out that i could use %M Month name (January..December)

I know i need

> '%M'

but how can i have it work in my case.

I also did try

> DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%M')

But the outome was 1

I did search other post before posting this one they did not help me.

```
SELECT 
    sum(totalExcl) AS total, saleType, date_add
FROM
    ex.ps_ox_quo
WHERE
    WEEK(date_add) = WEEK(UTC_TIMESTAMP())
        AND saleType IN ('IEW')
GROUP BY date_add
ORDER BY date_add DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `date_format()`:

```
SELECT sum(totalExcl) AS total, saleType, date_add,
       date_format(date_add, '%M')
FROM ex.ps_ox_quo
WHERE WEEK(date_add) = WEEK(UTC_TIMESTAMP()) AND
      saleType IN ('IEW')
GROUP BY date_add, saleType
ORDER BY date_add DESC;
```

Note:  You should probably include the year in the date comparison.

Comment: Worked great other comments also did work! I don't no what I did wrong when I used Date_Format

Answer (score 0):

You have  a datetime type for column date_add  you can use  MONTHNAME

```
SELECT 
sum(totalExcl) AS total, saleType, MONTHNAME(date_add)
FROM
ex.ps_ox_quo
WHERE
   WEEK(date_add) = WEEK(UTC_TIMESTAMP())
       AND saleType IN ('IEW')
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(date_add)
 ORDER BY MONTHNAME(date_add) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT 
sum(totalExcl) AS total, saleType, monthname(date_add)
FROM
ex.ps_ox_quo
WHERE
month(date_add) = month(UTC_TIMESTAMP())
    AND saleType IN ('IEW')
GROUP BY month(date_add)
ORDER BY month(date_add) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

select YEAR_MONTH(now()) AS current_month